# Convert JPEG-In-Tiff to normal TIff

Tags: image-processing, tiff, libtiff

I have a directory structure containing 300 gigs worth of Tiff Images. Some are encoded as Jpeg-in-Tiff, others as "Group 4 fax encoding". I need to change the format of all to the later without losing my folder structures.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Jpeg-in-Tiff is either grayscale or color while Group 4 fax is black/white only. Can you explain what you mean by "normal Tiff"? Maybe uncompressed Tiff?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any image viewer with a batch conversion shoudl do this I like [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.ca/)